# How to add triggers to find average,sum and number of rating for each movie in movie database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I have to add average and total number of ratings of the movie! Following are my tables and tiggers! Please improve this code!

```
create table fanrating
  (
   mov_id number(10),
   rate_avg number(1,1),
   rate_sum number,
   rate_count number
   );    
create table rating 
   ( 
    mov_id number(10) references movie(mov_id),
    userid varchar(20),
    rev_star number,
    primary key(mov_id,rev_star)
    );

delimiter $$
create or replace trigger bi_rating_trg
  before insert on fanrating
  for each row
begin
  set rate_sum = 0;
  set rate_count = 0;
  set rate_avg = null;
end;
$$
create or replace trigger ai_rating_trg
  after insert on rating
  for each row
begin
  update fanrating
     set rate_sum   = rate_sum + new.rev_star,
         rate_count = rate_count + 1,
         rate_avg   = rate_sum / rate_count
   where mov_id = new.mov_id;
end;
$$ delimiter;
```

It is showing error in all 3 set command in triggers and also error called encountered symbol $$, I am using Oracle SQL Delevepor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few objections:

- you don't need the first (before insert) trigger
- `new` and `old` values should be preceded by colon, i.e. `:new` and `:old`
- there's no `set` command in PL/SQL (at least, I don't know anything about it). If you want to *set* a variable to some value, you'd do it as `my_variable := :new.rate_star;`
- I have never used `delimiter`; don't know what you meant to do with it. Standard delimiters are semi-colon and slash, I'd suggest you to use them

Here's how I'd do what you are trying to do.

Tables first:

```
SQL> create table fanrating
  2    (mov_id     number(10),
  3     rate_avg   number,
  4     rate_sum   number,
  5     rate_count number
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create table rating
  2     (mov_id    number(10),
  3      userid    varchar(20),
  4      rev_star  number,
  5      primary key(mov_id,rev_star)
  6     );

Table created.
```

Trigger uses `merge` command which is also known as "upsert" as it does `update` (which is what I do if there's a match) or `insert` (if there's none):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ai_rating_trg
  2    after insert on rating
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    merge into fanrating f
  6      using (select :new.rev_star rev_star,
  7                    :new.mov_id   mov_id
  8             from dual
  9            ) x
 10      on (f.mov_id = x.mov_id)
 11    when matched then update set
 12      f.rate_sum = f.rate_sum + :new.rev_star,
 13      f.rate_count = f.rate_count + 1,
 14      f.rate_avg = round((f.rate_sum + :new.rev_star) /
 15                         (f.rate_count + 1), 2)
 16    when not matched then insert values
 17      (:new.mov_id, :new.rev_star, :new.rev_star, 1);
 18  end;
 19  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into rating (mov_id, userid, rev_star) values (1, 'Little', 3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From fanrating;

    MOV_ID   RATE_AVG   RATE_SUM RATE_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          3          1

SQL> insert into rating (mov_id, userid, rev_star) values (1, 'Foot', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From fanrating;

    MOV_ID   RATE_AVG   RATE_SUM RATE_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          4          2

SQL> insert into rating (mov_id, userid, rev_star) values (1, 'Scott', 4);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From fanrating;

    MOV_ID   RATE_AVG   RATE_SUM RATE_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2,67          8          3

SQL> insert into rating (mov_id, userid, rev_star) values (2, 'Foot', 5);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From fanrating;

    MOV_ID   RATE_AVG   RATE_SUM RATE_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2,67          8          3
         2          5          5          1

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: procedure + trigger]**

If it has to be a procedure, then - as I commented - move `MERGE` into it, use values you insert as parameters. Here's how:

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_mrg
  2    (par_mov_id   in number,
  3     par_userid   in varchar2,
  4     par_rev_star in number
  5    )
  6  as
  7  begin
  8    merge into fanrating f
  9      using (select par_rev_star rev_star,
 10                    par_mov_id   mov_id
 11             from dual
 12            ) x
 13      on (f.mov_id = x.mov_id)
 14    when matched then update set
 15      f.rate_sum = f.rate_sum + par_rev_star,
 16      f.rate_count = f.rate_count + 1,
 17      f.rate_avg = round((f.rate_sum + par_rev_star) /
 18                         (f.rate_count + 1), 2)
 19    when not matched then insert values
 20      (par_mov_id, par_rev_star, par_rev_star, 1);
 21  end;
 22  /

Procedure created.
```

Trigger now calls the procedure (instead of running `MERGE` itself):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ai_rating_trg
  2    after insert on rating
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    p_mrg (:new.mov_id, :new.userid, :new.rev_star);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Additional test:

```
SQL> insert into rating (mov_id, userid, rev_star) values (2, 'Mike', 2);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from fanrating;

    MOV_ID   RATE_AVG   RATE_SUM RATE_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2,67          8          3
         2        3,5          7          2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can i use stored procedure and triggers to do the same task? Stored procedure for finding avg,sum,count rate!!

Comment: You're welcome. A stored procedure? INSERT and MERGE would be part of it, I presume, while MOV_ID, USERID and REV_STAR would be procedure's parameters.

Comment: stored procedure and triggers to do the same task! Stored procedure for finding avg,sum,count rate!! can you help me to use stored procedure because i have to include one trigger and one procedure in my dbms mini project!

Comment: I edited my answer by adding the procedure + trigger option. Have a look, please.

Comment: "Some error" is difficult to debug, you have to provide some more info. Besides, it works in my example so ... you did something you shouldn't have. Aha, **that** error. Did you modify RATE_AVG datatype to **NUMBER** (as I did) for table FANRATING?

Comment: insert into rating (userid, mov_id, rev_star) values ('manu', 108, 3)
Error report -
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "MYPROJECT.AI_RATING_TRG", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MYPROJECT.AI_RATING_TRG'

Comment: As I said: NUMBER(1, 1) is too restrictive. Switch to NUMBER only.

Comment: Thank You So Much : ) I added triggers and procedure.Finally completed all parts of my mini project! Very Happy..tq

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create such a trigger for the `fanrating` table, but need to define default values during the creation such as :

```
create table fanrating
  (
   mov_id     number(10),
   rate_avg   number(1,1),
   rate_sum   number default 0,
   rate_count number default 0
   );
```

and create `insert or update` trigger for the `rating` table :

```
create or replace trigger ai_rating_trg 
after insert or update on rating
  for each row
begin 
update fanrating 
   set rate_sum = nvl(rate_sum,0) + nvl(:new.rev_star,0),
       rate_count = nvl(rate_count,0) + 1,
       rate_avg = nvl(rate_sum,0) / nvl(rate_count,1)
 where mov_id = :new.mov_id;
end;
/
```

where `nvl(..,0)` is used for converting `null` values to `zero`.